# Not accessed blocked sites with OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, vpn

I installed OpenVPN server and connect to it from my PC. On sites I can see, that my IP address - is VDS address, so all work fine. But I can't go to sites, which blocked in my county.

Firstly, I try to change DNS servers to Google DNS servers, but this is not help.

Configuration on server (*server.conf*):

```
port 7810

proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3

push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

Configuration on client (*openvpn.conf*):

```
remote 37.46.135.189 7810

push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"

tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
nobind 
proto tcp-client
dev tun0
pull   
resolv-retry infinite
comp-lzo
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
persist-tun
persist-key
verb 3 
route-method exe
route-delay 2
```

---

Why I can't take access to blocked sites and how it fix?

Comment: 37.46.135.189 is a russian IP, geolocation works with your serv er IPs as well

Comment: @Bruno9779, I know... All sites told, that I from Moskow. Sites, which allowed in Moskow, but denied in my country - is not working.

Comment: What happens if you login to the server and access the content directly with curl?

Comment: @Bruno9779, all works.

Comment: It looks like this might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/814137/how-to-make-sure-my-openvpn-client-is-trafficing-connections